# NotImplemented Error when retrieving an entity from Azure Table Storage

Tags: node.js, azure-table-storage

I'm using *Azure table storage* from a nodejs projects and interacting with the service through the  [@azure/data-tables](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/data-tables)  module.

I am able to write data to the table but I am unable to retrieve or update any data from the table, all functions other than createEntity fail with the `RestError`:

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "NotImplemented",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "The requested operation is not implemented on the specified resource."
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what I am running

```js
const tableClient = new TableClient(endpoint, 'tableName', credential);
 
let data = {
  rowKey: 'r1',
  partitionKey: 'p1',
  name: 'Bob'
}

await tableClient.createEntity(data)
let result = await tableClient.getEntity("p1", "r1")
```

I've confirmed permissions and am able to update / delete / retrieve entities from the equivalent PowerShell module

Comment: using this [code](https://i.imgur.com/D9vhIEj.png) able to retrieve the given [Entities](https://i.imgur.com/sO9jDIE.png) into Table.

Answer (score 0):

> I have referred this [MSDOC](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/data-tables?activeTab=readme) and git [@kazrael2119](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js) for Azure Tables.

- While creating a storage account make sure to enable All Service types.

[image]

- Replace your [AccountName](https://i.imgur.com/wntFAnq.png) and    [Accesskeys](https://i.imgur.com/OMaJUkd.png) in below code.

**Code:**

```js
const  {  TableClient,  AzureNamedKeyCredential  } = require("@azure/data-tables");
async  function  interactWithTableStorage()  {

const  accountName = "account name";

const  accountKey = "Accesskeys";

const  endpoint = `https://${accountName}.table.core.windows.net`;

const  tableName = "tablename";

const  credential = new  AzureNamedKeyCredential(accountName,  accountKey);

const  tableClient = new  TableClient(endpoint,  tableName,  credential);

const  entityData = {
partitionKey:  "p1",
rowKey:  "r1",
name:  "Bob"
};

try  {

await  tableClient.createEntity(entityData);
console.log("Entity created successfully!");

const  result = await  tableClient.getEntity("p1",  "r1");
console.log("Retrieved entity:",  result);

}  
catch (error)
 {
console.error("Error interacting with Azure Table Storage:",  error);
}
}
interactWithTableStorage();
```

**Retrieved Entity Output:**

[image]

****Note:****

If entity already exist as show in the below image, create new entities.

[image]